# Decryption - Get back the number after splitting C programming

Tags: c, encoding, decoding

I've just did an encryption using a simple C code. The encryption works like this, "Your application should read a 4 digit integer entered by the user and replace each digit with the result of adding 7 to the digit and getting the remainder after diving the new value by 10:
Let say I've entered `1234`, the value after encryption will be `8,9,0,1`.

I'm doing the encryption with the following code below:

```
num1 = ((digits/1000) + 7) % 10;
num2 = ((digits/100) + 7) % 10;
num3 = ((digits/10) + 7) % 10;
num4 = ((digits/1) + 7) % 10;
```

Now I would like to do a decryption, getting back the value I've entered. I'm wondering if I'm able to do a reverse modulo? A backwards calculation for `%`?
Meaning if a = 3 + 4, a = 7.. So what is 7 = b  + 4 which is b = 7-4. I'm

What I've attempted so far is this:

```
dNum1= (digits/1000) % 10;
dNum2= (digits/100) %10;
dNum3= (digits/10) %10;
dNum4= (digits % 10)  ;
```

The question is now: How do I retrieve the original value from the decrypted value(`8,9,0,1`)? (Original Value: `1234`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you encoded each digit by adding 7, you need to decode by subtracting 7.  Then if the value is negative, add 10 to get back the expected value.

```
num1 = (digits/1000) - 7;
num2 = (digits/100) - 7;
num3 = (digits/10) - 7;
num4 = (digits % 10) - 7;
if (num1 < 0) num1+=10;
if (num2 < 0) num2+=10;
if (num3 < 0) num3+=10;
if (num4 < 0) num4+=10;
```

EDIT:

Better yet, you can add 3 and then mod by 10, which does the same thing.  Thanks to psmears for suggesting this.

```
num1 = ((digits/1000) + 3) % 10;
num2 = ((digits/100) + 3) % 10;
num3 = ((digits/10) + 3) % 10;
num4 = ((digits/1) + 3) % 10;
```

EDIT2:

If you're translating the decoded digits directly from the encoded digits without moving the values back to `digits` first, do this:

```
dNum1 = (num1 + 3) % 10;
dNum2 = (num2 + 3) % 10;
dNum3 = (num3 + 3) % 10;
dNum4 = (num4 + 3) % 10;
```

Comment: Or add 3 and then take (result%10). The advantage of this is that decryption is exactly the same as encryption, with the 7s swapped for 3s.

Comment: HI, it suppose to be dNum1,dNum2,dNum3,dNum4,etc. Sorry about it.  I'v also tried your code, but the decryption doesn't seems to be working

Comment: dNum1 = ((num1/1000) - 7);
    dNum2 = ((num2/100) - 7);
    dNum3 = ((num3/10) - 7);
    dNum4 = ((num4/1) -7) ;

Comment: The decrypt word I got back is 3334 instead

Comment: @dbush , i'm bringing it to your notice as you have enough rep to this action... in tag synonyms for **encryption**, I find **decryption**! aren't they the opposite?? i wanted to add those tags for these questions and i stumbled upon this...  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/encryption/synonyms) the link.

Comment: @ch3rub7 They're opposite operations, but are directly associated with each other, so I think it fits.  Besides, I don't think you can undo a tag synonym.

Comment: @dbush if they're opposites then they must be antonyms right :)

Answer (score 1):

that's an interesting question @stack. One thing I see is that you are using individual statements to assign values to `num1`,`num2`,`num3`,`num4`

> but **every encryption follows a defined pattern and implicit is that
>   every decryption does**

And if you are successful in finding such pattern(**Which I prefer to say mystery!**), then these kind of encryption are near solved!

So I decided to find the pattern and I was successful in finding it for your encryption. ones you find pattern, `for loop` is very useful to repeat the process and thus encode given number.(same for the decoding too)

**Note**: I Don't know whether you require such a solution, but this is more useful as there are less number of variables which is a characteristic of any good program. and this code is only for 4 digit numbers... feel free to ask me if you want to extend it to n digited numbers :)

so! Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    //encryrption
    int num,num1,i,e=0,d=0;
    printf("enter 4 digit number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    num1=num;
    for(i=3;i>=0;i--)
    {
        num1=(num)/(pow(10,i));
        num1=(num1+7)%10;
        e=(10*e)+num1;
    }
    printf("encryption = %d\n",e);


    //decryption:
    for(i=3;i>=0;i--)
    {
        num1=e/pow(10,i);
        num1=((num1-7)%10);
        d=(10*d)+num1;
    }
    printf("decryption = %d",d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'll try to understand your code, as I'm still new to C programming Language

Comment: sure, @stack any help let me know :)